# Text editor wrapping actual text - not display

Tags: text-editor

I see text online and text files that have been wrapped to 80 chars wide however I cannot seem to find a text editor or function that 'maintains' the wrapping to 80 characters - not just the appearance of the text but the actual text itself.

How do I do this in Notepad++? What about vim?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor does this kind of *hard* line wrapping. There is a line wrap margin define in the *Options, Properties* menu.

Zeus is *shareware*, but there is a *freeware* [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) version that also has this feature.